# Разница между личным и безличным предложением

Tags: семантика, смысл

Какая разница по смыслу:

Лодку унесло ветром. (безличное предложение)
Ветер унес лодку. (личное предложение)

Comment: Впервые встречаю такое предложение "Мне голодно". Я не специалист по русскому, но возможно там было опечатка вместо "Мне холодно"

Comment: Есть принцип: "Не уверен — не обгоняй". Ответ должен быть обоснован, а сомнениям место в комментариях. Из Нацкорпуса: Ночевать хочу в лавре, здесь **мне голодно**, неприютно. [А. Н. Толстой. Петр Первый. Книга первая (1930)];  А **мне голодно**, да и скука съела. [И. А. Бунин. Веселый двор (1911)]

Answer (score 2):

По смыслу разницы нет, но в безличном нам важнее объект воздействия, а в личном - субъект.

*Мы хотели порыбачить, но лодку унесло ветром*. Не столь важно почему, главное мы остались без лодки.

*Разыгралась сильная буря, и ветер унёс лодку*. Ветер был такой сильный, что даже унёс лодку (а мог бы и что другое, это не так важно).

Answer (score 2):

Безличные предложения описывают действия и события **как стихийные, не зависящие от воли человека.** Хотя субъект действия в таких предложениях может присутствовать, но он выражается не именительным, а косвенным падежом. Субъект в безличных предложениях не важен: нас интересует только действие, но не "действующее лицо".

Рассмотрим примеры:

1) Мы вдвоем с Рожковым принялись подтаскивать лодку, чтобы ее **не унесло ветром** и течением, а остальные люди побежали к камням. [В. К. Арсеньев. В горах Сихотэ-Алиня (1937)]

Здесь безличное предложение позволяет автору не фиксировать внимание читателя на ветре как таковом и не воспринимать как в качестве присутствующего субъекта.

2) Сравнить: Пока мы обнимались, **ветер унес** зонтик в море. [Геннадий Алексеев. Зеленые берега (1983-1984)]

Здесь особая тема: мы и ветер. Представление ветра третьим присутствующим лицом не мешает описанию событий.

Answer (score 1):

*Смысловой* разницы **нет**, но для выбора имеет значение *контекст*, к которому больше подходит тот или иной вариант. Здесь важен порядок слов, а личный или безличный характер предложения может иметь значение в очень редких случаях, например в сказке о Ветре, где *ветер* выступает как действующее лицо (тогда выбор - в пользу *личного* предложения).

1. Если предложению предшествуют рассуждения о том, куда могла деться лодка, то вариант "Лодку *унесло ветром*." выглядит как объяснение причины её пропажи, о которой уже известно. В частности это может быть ответной репликой в диалоге.
2. Если перед этим рассматриваются последствия какой-нибудь бури (с грозой, ветром и волнами), то одним из последствий (наряду напр. с возгоранием от удара молнии или затоплением погреба) могла быть потеря лодки. Тогда предложение "*Ветер унес лодку*." (все элементы сообщения одинаково важны для читателя или собеседника) больше подходит как элемент описания или перечисления последствий непогоды (выход реки из берегов затопил погреб; ветер унёс лодку и т. д.). При другом порядке слов ("лодку унёс *ветер*") акцент переносится на причину *уже известной* неприятности, поэтому такое предложение больше соответствовало бы контексту по п. 1.