# Правильно ли составлено безличное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика

Предложение: (1) **На них ветром (Т.п.) набросало   снегу (Р.п).**

**Грамматика такая:** безличная форма глагола + сущ. в Т.п. (субъект действия) + сущ. в Р.п. (объект действия). Родительный падеж — количественно-разделительный, набросало (чего?) снегу.

**Правильно ли составлено такое предложение** (правильно ли выбраны падежи)?

**Примечание**

Предложение (1) я составила, взяв за основу текст В. Астафьева, но добавила туда падежную форму ***ветром.***

Но вот закружилась поземка, потащило ветром снег по реке, зазвенели льдины, сдерживая порывы ветра; **на них набросало снегу,** окрепли спайки. [Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

2) Вопрос соотносится с другим предложением (2) : А на дню **чего** (Р.п.) только не принесёт **толпой** (Т.п.), текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!

["А на дню чего только не принесёт толпой, текущей ручейком под нашими окнами!" - всё ли понятно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/451750/%D0%90-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%91%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

3) **В конечном итоге меня интересует правильность построения предложения 2,** но для этого я сравниваю предложения (1) и (2), считая их грамматику (выбор падежей) одинаковой.

Comment: "А если так", то ветер будет два раза почти подряд, а всего будет три ветра в одной фразе, не многовато? Чем не устраивает авторский вариант?

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса, поэтому я  дополнила текст.  Предложения 1 и 2 имеют сходную грамматику, мне нужно проверить  правильность обоих предложений. Предложение 1 я взяла у Астафьева, только дополнила его падежной формой "снегом". (Текст был нужен только для этого).

Comment: Подобный вопрос задавался на форуме. И вы тоже отвечали на него. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440836/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: Серж, там нет ничего общего с моим вопросом. По сути речь идет о том, что грамматика предложения с ДВУМЯ  СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫМИ в Р.п. и Т. п вызывает сомнения. Подробности можно посмотреть по ссылке https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/451750/А-на-дню-чего-только-не-принесёт-толпой-текущей-ручейком-под-нашими-окнами  Там подобную конструкцию посоветовали изменить ввиду некорректности, я же думаю, что такая грамматика возможна. Но пока меня интересует грамматика того предложения, о котором я спрашиваю: есть ли в нем ошибки? Падежи правильные? Всего-то четыре слова, но никто не отвечает.

Comment: @Sharon,а в чем сомнение? Типичное безличное предложение, указывающее на стихийное явление. Родительный обусловлен здесь тем, что указывает на количество, а также семантикой глагола "набросать".

Comment: Серж, да, спасибо, я уже разобралась. Меня интересовало,  насколько понятны и употребительны  такие безличные предложения с Р.п. и Т.п. одновременно.